# -D_FORCE_INLINES added in the run_nvcc.cmake file is not removing the compile error

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to run a Cuda (version 7.5) code in Ubuntu 16.04. The code was written using Cuda 3.0 and ran fine on Ubuntu 11. In Ubuntu 16.04, I get this error:

```
    /usr/include/string.h: In function ‘void* __mempcpy_inline(void*, const void*, size_t)’:
    /usr/include/string.h:652:42: error: ‘memcpy’ was not declared in this scope
    return (char *) memcpy (__dest, __src, __n) + __n;
```

The solution is to add -D_FORCE_INLINES in the run_nvcc.cmake file according to many internet sources for the compile error, but the examples on the net seem to be relevant to different cmake files so I could not copy it exactly. I tried adding it in different places, but it's not working. I need to know the correct place to add -D_FORCE_INLINES. I have included the modified parts of the cmake file below, which varies with different versions of nvcc (I am guessing). Any help would be appreciated. The modified part of the cmake file is:

```
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-D_FORCE_INLINES") #tried adding it here first
    # For CUDA 2.3 and above, add the -D_FORCE_INLINES flag
    # for dependency generation and hope for the best.
    set(depends_CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS}")
    set(CUDA_VERSION @CUDA_VERSION@)
    if(CUDA_VERSION VERSION_GREATER "3.0")
        cmake_policy(PUSH)
        # CMake policy 0007 NEW states that empty list elements are not
        # ignored.  I'm just setting it to avoid the warning that's printed.
        cmake_policy(SET CMP0007 NEW)
        list(APPEND depends_CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "-D_FORCE_INLINES") 
        #second modification (appending the list)
        cmake_policy(POP)
    endif()
```

Answer (score 2):

I add this in the beginning of the CMakeLists.txt. And the problem has been solved.

> set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS -D_FORCE_INLINES)